# iOS location conversion

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am making an app that utilizes location and I noticed that the latitude and longitude  values used are in the form: 21.232 -54.234. Now when I find a specific location on `Google Maps` the Lat and Long values are displayed as: 23° 4.800', -34° 30.829'. (These are just made up values, nothing specific). I want to take locations I get from Google Map and put them in my app. Is there a conversion between the two forms?

Comment: What will be the input, a string as shown: "-34° 30.829'" or degrees and minutes: "34", "30.829".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
-(double) convertDMSToDD_deg:(NSString*)degrees min:(NSString* )minutes sec:(NSString*)seconds {
    int latsign=1;
    double degree=[degrees doubleValue];
    double minute=[minutes doubleValue];
    double second=[seconds doubleValue];
    if (degree<0){
        latsign = -1;
    }
    else{
        latsign=1;
    }
    double dd = (degree + (latsign* (minute/60.)) + (latsign* (second/3600.) ) ) ;
    return dd;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. The Google lat/lon does not have seconds, just degrees and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example converting the google lat/lon string to float values:

```
- (void)convertGoogleLatLonString:(NSString *)latLonString {
    latLonString = @"23° 4.800', -34° 30.829'"; // Cheat for demo
    NSLog(@"latLonString: %@", latLonString);

    NSArray *latLonArray = [latLonString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    float lat = [self convertGoogleLLString:latLonArray[0]];
    float lon = [self convertGoogleLLString:latLonArray[1]];

    NSLog(@"lat: %f", lat);
    NSLog(@"lon: %f", lon);
}

- (float)convertGoogleLLString:(NSString *)llString {
    NSString *pattern = @"(-?\\d+)[^0-9]+([-0-9.]+)";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                  error:nil];

    NSTextCheckingResult *tcResult = [regex firstMatchInString:llString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, llString.length)];
    NSString *degMatch = [llString substringWithRange:[tcResult rangeAtIndex:1]];
    float degees = [degMatch floatValue];
    NSString *minMatch = [llString substringWithRange:[tcResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
    float minutes = [minMatch floatValue];

    float latOrLon = [self decimalLatOrLonWithDegrees:degees minutes:minutes];

    return latOrLon;
}

- (float)decimalLatOrLonWithDegrees:(float)degees minutes:(float)minutes {
    minutes = (degees > 0) ? minutes : -minutes;
    float latOrLon = degees + minutes/60;

    return latOrLon;
}
```

NSLog output:

> latLonString: 23° 4.800', -34° 30.829'
>   lat: 23.080000
>   lon: -33.486183